# Recuperar dados de uma List View

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma ListVew, e nesta, tenho dois botões(excluir e cancelar)
minha lista é composta pelos seguintes itens:
ID(TextView), Nome(TextView), Apelido(TextView), e os botões citados acima.

Como eu faço para obter o ID, ao clicar no botão excluir?

Comment: Porque não coloca uma TAG nos botões representando o ID do item? No momento de popular o item da lista no `Adapter`, basta colocar o ID como tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode implementar uma `interface` que faça uma comunicação entre seu `adapter` e uma outra classe que deseja.
Crie uma `interface`:

```
public interface MyButtonListClickListener {
    public void onClickBtnExcluir(int id);
    public void onClickBtnCancelar(int id);

}
```

Em seu `adapter` crie um atributo dessa `interface` e um método 'set':

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
      private MyButtonListClickListener listener;

      .
      .
      .

      public void setOnMyButtonListClickListener(MyButtonListClickListener listener){
           this.listener = listener;
      }
}
```

Depois crie os eventos dos cliques nos botões no seu `adapter` e chame o respectivo método da sua `interface`:

```
btnExcluir.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
          if(listener != null){
               listener.onClickBtnExcluir(item.getId());
          }

     } 
});

btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v){
          if(listener != null){
               listener.onClickBtnCancelar(item.getId());
          }       
     } 
});
```

Note que há um teste se o `listener` não é nulo, isso é para que não haja a exceção quando sua `interface` ainda não foi implementada.
Depois, em qualquer classe que você utilize seu `adapter`, você poderá incluir essa `interface` e implementar os métodos `onClickBtnExcluir` e `onClickBtnCancelar` como desejar.
 A implementação da `interface` seria alguma coisa do tipo:

```
adapter.setOnMyButtonListClickListener(new MyButtonListClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClickBtnExcluir(int id) {
          //Implemente como quiser e use o ID para localizar seu item no banco
     }
     @Override
     public void onClickBtnCancelar(int id) {
          //Implemente como quiser e use o ID para localizar seu item no banco
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve implementar o clique desses botões dentro do seu adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);

    }

        final Item item = getItem(position);

        TextView id= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView nome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        TextView apelido = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.apelido);
        Button  btnExcluir = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnExcluir);
        Button btnCancelar = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar);



         id.setText(String.valueOf(item.getId());
         nome.setText(item.getNome());
         apelido.setText(item.getApelido());

        btnExcluir.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             //Exclua o item

         } 
           });

        btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v)
        {
             // Cancele o item
        } 
        });



    return v;

}
```

Após excluir ou cancelar um item, chame a função adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() do seu adapter.

Esse foi um exemplo simples. Pesquise sobre ViewHolder em adapters para listView.